# building windows binaries monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I just installed Lubuntu on my old computer, and I installed MonoDevelop and MonoGame.

The Linux template work flawlessly, but the windows template crashes.

What are the steps needed to compile a Windows binary using MonoGame and MonoDevelop on Linux?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry, I know this is old, but anyway, I didn't knew when I asked this question that you can't develop on linux, the only solution would be still using the content Importer from Visual Studio, grab the converted files and just use them on Monogame.